# List Validation Formula not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

I need your help to fix my issue, basically what I want is when users select B from choice filed, the next column become mandatory.

Below formula doesn't work:

```
=IF([A]="B", [TEST] = " "), TRUE, FALSE), TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=IF([A] = "B", IF([TEST] = "", FALSE, TRUE), TRUE)
```

OR

```
=IF([A] = "B", IF(ISBLANK([TEST]), FALSE, TRUE), TRUE)
```

**Reference**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))
2. [IS functions - ISBLANK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-586532cc-9888-4ca0-98b8-c874e4c8a087)

---

**Update from Comments**:

To make multiple columns mandatory, you can use OR function in 2nd condition like:

```
=IF([A] = "B", IF(OR([TEST] = "", [TEST1] = ""), FALSE, TRUE), TRUE)
```

OR

```
=IF([A] = "B", IF(OR(ISBLANK([TEST]), ISBLANK([TEST1])), FALSE, TRUE), TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ganesh. It worked. Also If I want to have another column for instance TEST1 then how it works. for instance if you select B, the column TEST and TEST1 become mandatory

Comment: Check updated answer for making multiple columns mandatory

Comment: Hi @Harris, does this answers your question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Comment: When I try and use this formula for a single column, my custom error message does not display, I just get this error at the very top of the form - `Error: The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again`.  Additionally, the form pops open a date picker for a required date field which already had a date specified.  I have posted a question about this behaviour here:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/307172

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula:**

```
=IF(ColumnA="B",IF(Text="******",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: OP wants to make 2nd field mandatory and not have fixed value in 2nd field.

Comment: Hello,Ganesh Sanap. Thank you for your guidance instructions. Have a nice day!